# Transforming Ethereum ABI(JSON) into Human-Readable ABI in Python

Tags: solidity, python, abi, interfaces

I know there is one example to do it: [ethersjs implementation](https://github.com/gnidan/abi-to-sol)

But how to transforming Ethereum ABI into Human-Readable ABI in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a human readable abi in ethers is handmade, made by humans. In order do do it promatically you need to write a JSON parser yourself which doesn't seems pratical since you can get the ABI from the etherscan or from artifact folder in hardhat/truffle.